# Confusing way of receiving inputs

Tags: python

A lot of the sample programs out there have this type of code for getting an input:

```
W = [int(_) for _ in input().split()]
```

Can someone please explain what is going on in that statement? I can't make sense of it as a whole, but I know what the functions are doing individually.

Comment: If you understand what each part does, what part of the combination is confusing you?

Comment: Your question is too broad; I closed it as a duplicate of the canonical *what's this loop thing in brackets* post. The `input()`, `int()` and `str.split()` methods are all well documented and easy enough to find.

Comment: Thank you, I did try searching first, but I didn't know what keywords to use.

Comment: Note that using `_` as the name for an object you are going to be using is not very Pythonic; typically, the underscore is used to indicate that the value won't be used.

Comment: I still don't understand the use of the _

Comment: @Barmar: it's a *what does the loop in brackets do* question. E.g. the question to which the answer is: *list comprehension*.

Comment: @shogun000 it's just a name like any other - the code would work the same if you replaced it with e.g. `foo`.

Comment: `_` is *just a name*, but in a loop context that would normally be used to mean *this value is going to be ignored*, by convention. This code breaks that convention by using `_` anyway. I'd have used `part` here, or something similarly descriptive: `[int(part) for part in input().split()]`

Answer (score 0):

`input()` accepts the users input and returns a `str`

`split()` will split the string on a delimeter, which by default is on whitespace

The remaining is a list comprehension to convert each of the split string items to `int`.

Comment: The OP stated: *I know what the functions are doing individually*.